# i need help on using post in asp.net mvc swet allert

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

[image]

[image]

I post the data in the first screenshot. And I'm warning you to wait on the button. In the second picture, I print on the screen that the registration has been completed successfully.

But I cannot transfer the data to the database.

For these screens, I am using js file in the back part.

I haven't been able to solve the problem. can you help me ?

```
<form class="form fv-plugins-bootstrap5 fv-plugins-framework" action="#" id="kt_modal_add_customer_form" data-kt-redirect="/Dashboard/Cari">
    <!--begin::Modal header-->
    <div class="modal-header" id="kt_modal_add_customer_header">
        <!--begin::Modal title-->
        <h2 class="fw-bolder">Yeni Cari</h2>
        <!--end::Modal title-->
        <!--begin::Close-->
        <div id="kt_modal_add_customer_close" class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-active-icon-primary">
            <!--begin::Svg Icon | path: icons/duotune/arrows/arr061.svg-->
            <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-1">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">
                    <rect opacity="0.5" x="6" y="17.3137" width="16" height="2" rx="1" transform="rotate(-45 6 17.3137)" fill="black"></rect>
                    <rect x="7.41422" y="6" width="16" height="2" rx="1" transform="rotate(45 7.41422 6)" fill="black"></rect>
                </svg>
            </span>
            <!--end::Svg Icon-->
        </div>
        <!--end::Close-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Modal header-->
    <!--begin::Modal body-->
    <div class="modal-body py-10 px-lg-17">
        <!--begin::Scroll-->
        <div class="scroll-y me-n7 pe-7" id="kt_modal_add_customer_scroll" data-kt-scroll="true" data-kt-scroll-activate="{default: false, lg: true}" data-kt-scroll-max-height="auto" data-kt-scroll-dependencies="#kt_modal_add_customer_header" data-kt-scroll-wrappers="#kt_modal_add_customer_scroll" data-kt-scroll-offset="300px" style="max-height: 397px;">
            <!--begin::Input group-->
            <div class="fv-row mb-7 fv-plugins-icon-container">
                <!--begin::Label-->
                <label class="required fs-6 fw-bold mb-2">Cari Kodu</label>
                <!--end::Label-->
                <!--begin::Input-->
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="" name="CariKodu" value="@ViewData["CariKodu"]">
                <!--end::Input-->
                <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <!--end::Input group-->
            <!--begin::Input group-->
            <div class="fv-row mb-7 fv-plugins-icon-container">
                <!--begin::Label-->
                <label class="required fs-6 fw-bold mb-2">Firma Ünvanı</label>
                <!--end::Label-->
                <!--begin::Input-->
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="" name="FirmaUnvani">
                <!--end::Input-->
                <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <!--end::Input group-->
            <!--begin::Input group-->
            <div class="fv-row mb-7 fv-plugins-icon-container">
                                <!--begin::Label-->
                                <label class="required fs-6 fw-bold mb-2">Ticari Ünvan</label>
                                <!--end::Label-->
                                <!--begin::Input-->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="" name="TicariUnvani">
                                <!--end::Input-->
                                <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Input group-->
                            <!--begin::Input group-->
                            <div class="fv-row mb-7 fv-plugins-icon-container">
                                <!--begin::Label-->
                                <label class="fs-6 fw-bold mb-2">
                                    <span class="required">E-Posta</span>
                                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle ms-1 fs-7" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="Aktivasyon için E-Posta Adresi Zorunludur" aria-label="Aktivasyon için E-Posta Adresi Zorunludur"></i>
                                </label>
                                <!--end::Label-->
                                <!--begin::Input-->
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="" name="EPosta">
                                <!--end::Input-->
                                <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Input group-->
                            <!--begin::Input group-->
                            <div class="fv-row mb-7 fv-plugins-icon-container">
                                <!--begin::Label-->
                                <label class="required fs-6 fw-bold mb-2">Vergi Dairesi</label>
                                <!--end::Label-->
                                <!--begin::Input-->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="" name="VDairesi">
                                <!--end::Input-->
                                <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Input group-->
                            <!--begin::Input group-->
                            <div class="fv-row mb-7 fv-plugins-icon-container">
                                <!--begin::Label-->
                                <label class="required fs-6 fw-bold mb-2">Vergi Numarası</label>
                                <!--end::Label-->
                                <!--begin::Input-->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="" name="VNo">
                                <!--end::Input-->
                                <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Input group-->
                        </div>
                        <!--end::Scroll-->
                    </div>
                    <!--end::Modal body-->
                    <!--begin::Modal footer-->
                    <div class="modal-footer flex-center">
                        <!--begin::Button-->
                        <button type="reset" id="kt_modal_add_customer_cancel" class="btn btn-light me-3">İptal</button>
                        <!--end::Button-->
                        <!--begin::Button-->
                        <button type="submit" id="kt_modal_add_customer_submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span class="indicator-label">Gönder</span>
                            <span class="indicator-progress">
                                Lütfen Bekleyiniz...
                                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                        <!--end::Button-->
                    </div>
                    <!--end::Modal footer-->
                    <div></div>
                </form>
                <!--end::Form-->
```

```
"use strict";
var KTModalCustomersAdd = function () {
    var t, e, o, n, r, i;
    return {
        init: function () {
            i = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector("#kt_modal_add_customer")), r = document.querySelector("#kt_modal_add_customer_form"), t = r.querySelector("#kt_modal_add_customer_submit"), e = r.querySelector("#kt_modal_add_customer_cancel"), o = r.querySelector("#kt_modal_add_customer_close"), n = FormValidation.formValidation(r, {
                fields: {
                    CariKodu: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Firmanın Cari Kodu Olmadan Kayıt Açamazsınız."
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    FirmaUnvani: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Firma Ünvanı Olmadan Kayıt Açamazsınız."
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "TicariUnvani": {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Firmanın Ticari Ünvanı Olmadan Kayıt Açamazsınız."
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "EPosta": {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Aktivasyon İşlemi İçin E-Posta Adresini Girmelisiniz."
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    VDairesi: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Firmanın Vergi Dairesi Olmadan Kayıt Açamazsınız."
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    VNo: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Firmanın Vergi Numarası Olmadan Kayıt Açamazsınız."
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    city: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "City is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    state: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "State is required"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    postcode: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: "Postcode is required"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger,
                    bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap5({
                        rowSelector: ".fv-row",
                        eleInvalidClass: "",
                        eleValidClass: ""
                    })
                }
            }), $(r.querySelector('[name="country"]')).on("change", (function () {
                n.revalidateField("country")
            })), t.addEventListener("click", (function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(), n && n.validate().then((function (e) {
                    console.log("validated!"), "Valid" == e ? (t.setAttribute("data-kt-indicator", "on"), t.disabled = !0, setTimeout((function () {
                        t.removeAttribute("data-kt-indicator"), Swal.fire({
                            text: "Form bilgileri başarıyla gönderildi!",
                            icon: "success",
                            buttonsStyling: !1,
                            confirmButtonText: "Tamam, Anladım",
                            customClass: {
                                confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                            },

                        }).then((function (e) {
                            e.isConfirmed && (i.hide(), t.disabled = !1, window.location = r.getAttribute("data-kt-redirect"))
                        }))
                    }), 2e3)) : Swal.fire({
                        text: "Maalesef bazı hatalar tespit edildi, lütfen tekrar deneyin.",
                        icon: "error",
                        buttonsStyling: !1,
                        confirmButtonText: "Tamam, Anladım!",
                        customClass: {
                            confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                        }
                    })
                }))
            })), e.addEventListener("click", (function (t) {
                t.preventDefault(), Swal.fire({
                    text: "İptal etmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?",
                    icon: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: !0,
                    buttonsStyling: !1,
                    confirmButtonText: "Evet, Kaydı İptal Et",
                    cancelButtonText: "Hayır, Devam Et",
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
                        cancelButton: "btn btn-active-light"
                    }
                }).then((function (t) {
                    t.value ? (r.reset(), i.hide()) : "cancel" === t.dismiss && Swal.fire({
                        text: "Formunuz iptal edilmedi!.",
                        icon: "error",
                        buttonsStyling: !1,
                        confirmButtonText: "Tamam, Anladım!",
                        customClass: {
                            confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                        }
                    })
                }))
            })), o.addEventListener("click", (function (t) {
                t.preventDefault(), Swal.fire({
                    text: "İptal etmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?",
                    icon: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: !0,
                    buttonsStyling: !1,
                    confirmButtonText: "Evet, İptal Et!",
                    cancelButtonText: "Hayır, Devam Et",
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
                        cancelButton: "btn btn-active-light"
                    }
                }).then((function (t) {
                    t.value ? (r.reset(), i.hide()) : "cancel" === t.dismiss && Swal.fire({
                        text: "Formunuz iptal edilmedi!.",
                        icon: "error",
                        buttonsStyling: !1,
                        confirmButtonText: "Tamam, Anladım!",
                        customClass: {
                            confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                        }
                    })
                }))
            }))
        }
    }
}();
KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded((function () {
    KTModalCustomersAdd.init()
}));
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Cari(Cariler p)
{
    db.Cariler.Add(p);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(p);
}
```

I tried using the post structure with ajax inside the js file. I was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I have completed the sweet alert record adding process as follows. It works successfully. Topic can be closed.

```
console.log(e);
                debugger;
                var EmpModel = {
                    CariKodu: $("#CariKodu").val(),
                    FirmaUnvani: $("#FirmaUnvani").val(),
                    TicariUnvani: $("#TicariUnvani").val(),
                    EPosta: $("#EPosta").val(),
                    VDairesi: $("#VDairesi").val(),
                    Telefon1: $("#Telefon1").val(),
                    VNo: $("#VNo").val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Dashboard/Cari",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(EmpModel),
                    success: function (msg) { },
                    error: function (err) { alert(err.responseText) }
                })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).